# Selecting rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL

Tags: sql, max, distinct

I have two tables that I'm having difficulty with. OrderHed & UD11. OrderHed has 1 value for OrderNum=70960, but UD11 has 4 records for 70960.

I'm trying to return the max value of UD11.Key5 as a distinct record - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

```
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT OrderHed.OrderNum,
    OrderHed.OpenOrder,
    OrderHed.OrderDate,
    OrderRel.Plant,
    OrderHed.EntryPerson,
    OrderHed.Company,
    Erp.Customer.CustID,
    Erp.Customer.NAME,
    Erp.InvcDtl.InvoiceNum,
    SUM(OrderDtl.ExtPriceDtl) AS Expr1,
    OrderHed.PONum,
    Ice.UD11.Key1,
    Ice.UD11.Key2,
    Ice.UD11.Key3,
    Ice.UD11.Key4,
    MAX(Ice.UD11.Key5) AS Expr2,
    Ice.UD11.Character01,
    Ice.UD11.Number01,
    Ice.UD11.Date01,
    Ice.UD11.Date02,
    Ice.UD11.Date03,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar01,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar02,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar03,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar04,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar05,
    OrderHed.OrderComment
FROM Erp.Customer
RIGHT JOIN Ice.UD11
RIGHT JOIN Erp.OrderHed AS OrderHed ON Ice.UD11.Company = OrderHed.Company
    AND Ice.UD11.Key1 = OrderHed.OrderNum
LEFT JOIN Erp.OrderRel AS OrderRel
RIGHT JOIN Erp.OrderDtl AS OrderDtl ON OrderRel.Company = OrderDtl.Company
    AND OrderRel.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum
    AND OrderRel.OrderLine = OrderDtl.OrderLine ON OrderHed.Company = OrderDtl.Company
    AND OrderHed.OrderNum = OrderDtl.OrderNum ON Erp.Customer.Company = OrderHed.Company
    AND Erp.Customer.CustNum = OrderHed.CustNum LEFT JOIN Erp.InvcDtl RIGHT JOIN Erp.ShipDtl ON Erp.InvcDtl.Company = Erp.ShipDtl.Company
    AND Erp.InvcDtl.OrderNum = Erp.ShipDtl.OrderNum
    AND Erp.InvcDtl.OrderLine = Erp.ShipDtl.OrderLine
    AND Erp.InvcDtl.OrderRelNum = Erp.ShipDtl.OrderRelNum ON OrderRel.Company = Erp.ShipDtl.Company
    AND OrderRel.OrderNum = Erp.ShipDtl.OrderNum
    AND OrderRel.OrderLine = Erp.ShipDtl.OrderLine
    AND OrderRel.OrderRelNum = Erp.ShipDtl.OrderRelNum GROUP BY OrderHed.OrderNum,
    OrderHed.OrderDate,
    OrderRel.Plant,
    OrderHed.EntryPerson,
    OrderHed.Company,
    OrderHed.OpenOrder,
    Erp.Customer.CustID,
    Erp.Customer.NAME,
    Erp.InvcDtl.InvoiceNum,
    OrderHed.PONum,
    Ice.UD11.Key1,
    Ice.UD11.Key2,
    Ice.UD11.Key3,
    Ice.UD11.Key4,
    Ice.UD11.Character01,
    Ice.UD11.Number01,
    Ice.UD11.Date01,
    Ice.UD11.Date02,
    Ice.UD11.Date03,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar01,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar02,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar03,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar04,
    Ice.UD11.ShortChar05,
    OrderHed.OrderComment HAVING (OrderHed.Company = N'011')
    AND (Erp.InvcDtl.InvoiceNum IS NULL)
    AND (OrderHed.OrderNum = 70960)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNum ORDER BY key5 DESC) rn
        FROM    (... /* my huge query */) q
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: So I want to put another SELECT statement inside my FROM statement?

Comment: @Machzy: yes, put your whole query inside the parens and don't forget to alias it (the `q` after the closing paren)